# Can i use TFS Rest API's to subscribe to TFS events?

Tags: tfs

As given in the below URL , can i use this to subscribe to onprimise TFS events ?? In TFS 2015 or TFS 2016 ?

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/service-hooks/events

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I just tested creating a subscription on TFS 2015.3 with the REST API below, and got a successful result:

```
POST http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/hooks/subscriptions?api-version=1.0
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "publisherId": "tfs",
  "eventType": "build.complete",
  "resourceVersion": "1.0-preview.1",
  "consumerId": "webHooks",
  "consumerActionId": "httpRequest",
  "publisherInputs": {
    "buildStatus": "Failed",
    "definitionName": "MyWebSite CI",
    "projectId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  },
  "consumerInputs": {
    "url": "https://myservice/myhookeventreceiver"
  }
}
```